# If statement not working as expected on combined enum value

Tags: c#, .net, debugging, if-statement

This is a quirky one.

I have the following code...

```
foreach (IScanTicket ticket in this) {
    if (ticket.Status == TicketStatus.Created || ticket.Status == (TicketStatus.Transfered | TicketStatus.Created))
        return ticket;
    }
}
```

When I run this, where the status is `Created|Transferred`, the if statement seems to fail (not do what it's suppose to).

The interesting thing is that if I debug and step through the code and watch the statement, it always returns `TRUE` in my debugger, yet it fails to enter the block when I step through the code.

Why would the debugger show that the statement is `true`, yet continue like it's not?  It's like what the debugger is telling me fibs.

Has anyone ever experienced this?

*P.S. I'm using Xamarin studio 5.9.7*

Comment: How is `TicketStatus`? Is that an enum with `[Flags]` attribute?

Comment: What is the value of `ticket.Status` when it fails, but you expect if to be `true`?

Comment: Interesting...if I swap the enum join around (eg. `(TicketStatus.Created | TicketStatus.Transfered)`) it seems to work.    Being the enum is a `byte` flagged-based enum, I would have thought it would not have made a difference?..  any ideas why?

Comment: @GuyPark Do you have `[Flags]` attribute assigned to your enum?

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek yep, a `byte` enum with `[Flags]`.

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev the `ticket.status` is `TicketStatus.Created | TicketStatus.Transfered` at this point.    Seems order makes a difference.   Any ideas why this matters in C# since it's technically just a byte value?

Comment: @GuyPark Could you also show the code of `TicketStatus`, please?

Comment: Try cleaning your solution and rebuilding it, sometimes it may happen due to the presence of old files in the bin folder of solution(bin folder may differ for xamarin solution).

Answer (score 3):

Too long for a comment:

Actually, the `[Flags]` attribute does not change an enum's semantics at all, it's most popularly used by the `ToString` method to emit a series of names rather than a number for a combined value.

Let's say your enum was declared like this (without the `Flags` attribute):

```
enum TicketStatus
{
    Created = 1,
    Transferred = 2,
    Sold = 4
}
```

You could still combine different members and do any arithmetic that applies to a Flags enum:

```
TicketStatus status = TicketStatus.Created | TicketStatus.Transferred;
```

However, the following will print `3`:

```
Console.WriteLine(status);
```

But if you add the `[Flags]` attribute, it will print `Created, Transferred`.

Also, it's important to note that by `TicketStatus.Created | TicketStatus.Transferred` you're really doing a bitwise `OR` on the underlying integer value, notice how in our example that the assigned values are unambiguously combinable:

```
Created :    0001
Transferred: 0010
Sold:        0100
```

Therefore a value of `3` can be unambiguously determined as a combination of `Created` and `Transferred`. However if we had this:

```
enum TicketStatus
{
    Created = 1,      // 0001
    Transferred = 2,  // 0010
    Sold = 3,         // 0011
}
```

As it is obvious by the binary representations, combining values and checking against members is problematic as combined members could be ambiguous. e.g. what is `status` here?

```
status = TicketStatus.Created | TicketStatus.Transferred;
```

Is it `Created, Transferred` or is it really `Sold`? However, the compiler won't complain if you try to do it, which could lead to hard to track down bugs like yours, where some check is not working as you expect it to, so it's on you to ensure the definition is sane for bitwise mixing and comparing.

On a related note, since your `if` statement is really only checking if the ticket has a `Created` status, regardless of being combined with other members, here's a better way to check for that (.NET >= 4):

```
status.HasFlag(TicketStatus.Created)
```

or (.NET <4):

```
(status & TicketStatus.Created) != 0
```

As to why your enum did not work as expected, it is almost certainly because you did not explicitly specify unambigously bitwise combinable values to its members (typically powers of two).

Comment: Absolutely, and that is how I understand it., which is why it was confusing me as to why it was not working. Technically you are spot on, but what I was finding was it was not the case when actually running, until I added the `[flags]` attribute.  Hence the question.   It would be interesting to know what the compiler/JIT was thinking as the debugger was giving me what you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @MarcinJuraszek and @YeldarKurmangaliyev.

Seems the `[Flags]` attribute **wasn't** set on the enum as I originally thought.   Adding this attribute now makes the enum work in either combination.

So it seems that not having this attribute effects the order of joined enum values.

Comment: Enums without hardcoded values auto number themselves.  With a flag enum it's better practice to explicitly define the values.  E.g. 0, 0x1, 0x2, 0x4, 0x8, 0x16, 0x32, 0x64.. etc  If you hard code the values it will work whether it has [Flags] on it or not.  Not hardcoding them could bite you later, because if you add a new value in the middle of the existing values it will offset the old values, which could screw up your data (e.g. in a database) and produce skewed results down the line that will not be obvious to troubleshoot.

Comment: @Ryios If you are storing enum values in a database, it's always a good idea to hardcode them. If you are not, there's no reason to.

Comment: I always hard code them just in case the compiler doesn't do it.  Technically my code was right, but realistically the compiler was thinking something else.  I'm just going to put this down to a  quirk in the compiler and trap to watch out for.    I can explain why at this point, but when I added the `[flags]` attribute, it started to behave as expected.   Like @Saeb-Amini mentioned, It might have been better to use the .HasFlag() method, but being old school c++, i usually go back to my roots in bitwise coding.  :)